# JRDataset property CSV file

Tags: csv, dataset, jasper-reports

I have a build up a report with a .CSV input file as DataAdapter. After that I needeed a table to put some data into a it and a linked dataset. The problem is: if I leave blank the section "Default Data Adapter" in my Dataset1, no data will be displayed. In fact, to fix this report I had to export my DataAdapter as myDataAdapter.xml and then put this file in the section "**Default Data Adapter**" of my **Dataset1** (as shown in the attached picture).
[image]

Working with database I have never set up this property.

Is there a way to pass this property as Param? (I have a java code in which I call jasperReport and I want to pass this object dinamically).

Or is there a way the report works without setting this property?

In the section Table>Dataset I have this situation:

[image]

where I set up JRDatasource expression, but it is not working...

I have one more problem. Can I set dinamically the location of my .csv inside the DataAdapter.xml?

[image]

Is it possible to implement "myDataAdapter.xml" from java code and pass it to the report??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java code you can set properties on the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport` instance like in this sample [here](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/demo/samples/exceldataadapter/src/ExcelDataAdapterApp.java#L89-L90), from the official repository. The relevant code looks like this:

```
...
JasperReport jasperReport = ...
...
jasperReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("build/reports/ExcelXlsxQeDataAdapterReport.jasper");
jasperReport.setProperty(DataAdapterParameterContributorFactory.PROPERTY_DATA_ADAPTER_LOCATION, "data/XlsxQeDataAdapter.xml");
...
```

The property of interest is `net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter` and is stored in `DataAdapterParameterContributorFactory.PROPERTY_DATA_ADAPTER_LOCATION`

The data adapter file is a convenience method to pass a series of parameters from which a `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRCsvDataSource` is built. If you want to skip passing this property, you would have to manually provide the built-in parameters listed in the [`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRCsvQueryExecuterFactory.CSV_BUILTIN_PARAMETERS`](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRCsvQueryExecuterFactory.java#L232).

Comment: Ok, I will try this code!! But, in the section "Default Data Adapter" of Dataset1 (first attached pictures) what kind of value I have to insert?

Comment: The path to the data adapter. But it looks like you already did that and got it working. In Jaspersoft Studio, at least.

Comment: I added the java's code lines and it is working now (I had to delete the data adapter path in Jaspersoft Studio because I am passing it from java code). But I have one more problem: The path location inside my xml Data Adapter is fixed (attached picture). Is there a way to pass a dynamic location? I tried a paramater but it is not working.